# Layered windows, UpdateLayeredWindow, alpha blending and mouse events

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, alphablending, layered-windows

In Windows Forms and C#, I'm using a form with the WS_EX_LAYERED style, and calling *UpdateLayeredWindow* to set the background to an image that is transparent/alpha blending:

```
NativeMethods.BLENDFUNCTION blend = new NativeMethods.BLENDFUNCTION();
blend.BlendOp = NativeMethods.AC_SRC_OVER;
blend.BlendFlags = 0;
blend.SourceConstantAlpha = 255;
blend.AlphaFormat = NativeMethods.AC_SRC_ALPHA;

NativeMethods.UpdateLayeredWindow(form.Handle, screenDc, ref topPos, ref size, 
    memDc, ref pointSource, 0, ref blend, NativeMethods.ULW_ALPHA);
```

On the regions of the form where the image is transparent, the form does not receive mouse events. They go to the window that is under the form.

Is there a window style or an option that can be set to enable the form to receive mouse events (mouse move, mouse down, etc.) on its entire surface?

Answer (score 1):

From [Layered Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997507.aspx#layerwin_topic2b)

## Hit Testing

Hit testing of a layered window is based on the shape and transparency of the window. This means that the areas of the window that are color-keyed or whose alpha value is zero will let the mouse messages through.
If the layered window has the WS_EX_TRANSPARENT extended window style, the shape of the layered window will be ignored and the mouse events will be passed to the other windows underneath the layered window.

I would try rmeoving that WS_EX_TRANSPARENT style

Comment: I didn't set the WS_EX_TRANSPARENT style in the first place. Anyway, I tried removing it, and it doesn't work. Mouse events on transparent areas still go through. (To check, I also tried setting it, and when set, all the mouse events go through, even on non-transparent areas.)

Comment: @Jamrelian Can you maybe cheat and set the transparent areas to alpha value 1 (of 255). I wonder if that would basically be clear but not fall through

Comment: Unfortunately I don't control the image with alpha blending that is set as the background, the user selects it. This means I should programmatically check and change the alpha value of every pixel in any loaded image. Sounds like a lot of performance issues...

Comment: @Jamrelian Why is the window layered in the first place, sounds like it does exactly what you don't want?

Comment: It's a kind of transparent splash screen window, that's why it needs to be layered and with alpha blending, but the user is able to select another image(s).